# Styled cross-platform native widgets and windows

Tags: c, user-interface, cross-platform

I'm looking for a reasonably cross-platform way to render windows and widgets and style them the way I want without losing the ability to interface with the OS-preferred ways of doing things like redrawing or text input. I am also keen on knowing how Photoshop did this on Windows, as a concrete example.

I'm writing a program primarily for myself but I want to leave open a possibility to share it with others afterwards if it would be useful for more people. I want to really customize its look-and-feel but would like to keep it using native GUI libraries, such as windows forms or something more specific than just rendering my inerface to X11 windows. As I have to use it both on Windows and X11 the solution would preferably be cross-platform but I'm ready to implement multiple UI front-ends if needed, too, if it would provide reasonably consistent looks on both systems. OSX support is a plus, but really far from mandatory. I don't see myself porting this to OSX quite yet. I have barely started.

The reason I want theming is simple: I like dark themes because they are very relaxing to my eyes. On Windows, Microsoft Visual Studio and Adobe Photoshop (Photoshop as the only one and VS by default) display a dark theme and I find it enjoyable to work with these pieces of software for the sole rest that my eyes get. However, both of these, as it seems, use Windows' native controls (I can get to individual widgets in these using Hawkeye and they seem to have descriptive class names, consistent with what they represent).

I see this done way more on Windows than on X11 systems (GNOME, KDE, XFCE on GNU/Linux), maybe because Windows' theming is as rigid as it can get and on X11 window managers and GUI toolkits (KDE with Qt comes to my mind) are really flexible at that so apps needn't implement their own styles when the user can choose them DE-wide quite freely.

I didn't really do GUI programming at all before so I feel a little lost. I would like to refrain from drawing all GUI in a window with an OpenGL context, because I like the idea of the OS drawing legible, subpixel-level text for me, according to the users' settings, and handling partial window redraws instead of full ones. I would also like to integrate with the operating system with, for example, text input. As I said, I would like to share the software some day, so it'd be nice if I don't have to make fundamental changes beforehand.

I'm using C for core code as I've grown tired of futile OOP (whose most benefits I fail to understand if I'm the only one working on the project) with C++ and just want to write code, but I see that GUI libraries for C are in deficit, so I'm ready to write the GUI front-end in another language and link it against my C object files.

Bottom line, to focus on a multiplatform example, how does Photoshop go about redrawing native Windows widgets? I see it looks very consistent on Windows and Mac. Supporting X11 would be less of a problem, as I wouldn't force my styling in the X11 version, just proxy all through a standard widget library (Gtk+? Qt?) and let the desktop environment/window managers/whatevs style it for me. Though I don't know enough on how window and widget management works on GNU/Linux desktop environments to make assumptions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: If you're looking for a cross-platform GUI is with native look, I'd recommend using Qt. I haven't used the native C++ bindings but I have used the python ones (PySide).

Comment: I'm looking for a reasonably cross-platform way to render windows and widgets and style them the way I want without losing the ability to interface with the OS-preferred ways of doing things like redrawing or text input. I was also asking how Photoshop did this on Windows, as a concrete example. Edited into the question.

@cpburnz: Can I customize the styling like the examples I provided do?

Comment: For cross platform with native controls, wxwidgets is worth a look

Comment: @geomaster Due to the age of Photoshop, I'd guess they use a custom GUI library which may use the underlying OS libraries or just imitates them (per supported OS).

Comment: @geomaster Qt does allow custom styles and themeing, though I don't have personal experience using them. Example <http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion/>.

Comment: I didn't know Qt was this flexible when it comes to styles, @cpburnz. Thanks for the answer, it seems like I'll go with it, for now at least. You may want to post this as an answer so I can accept it. Or not, I'm not sure how things work on StackOverflow quite yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: This is purely anecdotal and based upon my own assumptions.

Due to Photoshop's age, I would assume it uses its own custom, proprietary GUI toolkit. It may use the underlying OS's native toolkit but more than likely it just mimics the look and feel. I know Sublime Text uses a custom toolkit made by the developer.

I have made simple applications with .NET, GTK ([PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)), and Qt ([PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide)). If you want to support multiple platforms I'd really recommend using a cross-platform toolkit instead of writing the GUI specific to each OS because of the amount of work involved.

- I liked .NET but it's not really cross-platform (I'm not sure what all is supported by [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)).
- GTK2 (via PyGTK) was fairly straight forward to us. It looked good on Linux (Ubuntu) but I could not get some custom styles working properly in Windows (unless Windows 95 looks good). I also found PyGTK's documentation lacking. GTK3 is the way forward, but last I knew it was still under heavy development and isn't stable on Windows (yet).
- I will say I liked Qt (PySide) the best. I found its documentation and examples better than GTK's. It supports native OS themeing along with [custom styles and themes](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion/) (I don't have personal experience with this though). By default it looks native on both Windows (XP and 7), and Linux (Ubuntu).
- I have no experience with [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) so I have no say on it, but it is cross-platform.

I would recommend looking into using Qt, though you would have to use C++ (or a higher-level language with available bindings).

Comment: Very informative, thanks a bunch. I'll look mostly into Qt. I just have one question, and despite it sounding like it's a common thing to ask, I've been unable to find an answer—what is the difference between "OpenGL" archives and the other ones on Qt's website?

Comment: @geomaster Looking under the downloads page, it looks to me like whether that  Qt installation supports OpenGL or not. I.e., let Qt handle the OpenGL context which would be required to have an OpenGL canvas inside of a Qt-managed window.

Comment: Yeah, I'd anticipated as much. What had me confused is that these OpenGL archives were the same size or even smaller than the non-OpenGL ones. Thanks for the clarification.